# To store different struct in a array and update the array when struct value changed in swift

Tags: arrays, swift, struct

[image]

I want to save different struct in a array. And i want to update the array when any of the struct value changed.

My structs are -

```
struct A{
    var name: String
    var village: String
}
struct B{
    var name: String
    var village: String
}
struct C{
    var name: String
    var village: String
}
struct D{
    var name: String
    var village: String
}
struct E{
    var name: String
    var village: String
}
```

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var dataArray = [A.self, B.self, C.self, D.self, E.self] as [Any]
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
  
    }

    private func changeStructValue(){
        
        //update struct D Value
        if let nameOne = textFieldOne.text{
        let a = A(name: nameOne, village: “abcd”)
        dataArray[0] = a
        }
        
        //update struct D Value
        if let nameFour = textfieldFour.text{
            let d = D(name: nameFour, village: “efgh”)
            dataArray[3] = d
        }
    }
```

Can I do like this? Or I am doing in wrong way?

And also I want to delete the struct which is nil from the array -

```
 private func submitButton(){
     
     //Remove empty struct
     dataArray = dataArray.filter { $0 != nil }
 }
}
```

can I try like this?

Comment: Why do you have 5 structurally identical struct definitions?

Comment: i have 5 textfields present in 5 different cells of a tableview. When I am entering the value in the textfield, I want to update the struct . So I have taken 5 different struct .

Comment: @TapanRaut why not use one struct and different instances of the same struct?

Comment: @gcharita thanks for your response. Actually i am unable to do this by using the same struct. can yo suggest how to do this, so that the array will be updated according to the textfield present in tableview.

Comment: @TapanRaut your TableView has static or dynamic cells? Will be helpful if you add more of your code in the question.

Comment: my tableview has dynamic cell. A "add button" is there. by pressing the "add button" the number of cell will be increased. so that my array size is not constant. it can be any numbers.

Comment: Hi @gcharita. i have added a image of my tableview in the question. please see it.

Comment: @TapanRaut this is interesting. So, each struct will represent one cell that has the information that shown in the screenshot? And if you can add dynamically new cells you cannot create new structs, let's say struct F.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222325/discussion-between-tapan-raut-and-gcharita).

Answer (score 3):

I think you can simplify your code by using a protocol with the shared properties and methods:

```
protocol MyProtocol {
    var name: String { get set }
    var village: String { get set }
}

struct A: MyProtocol {
    var name: String
    var village: String
}
struct B: MyProtocol {
    var name: String
    var village: String
}
struct C: MyProtocol{
    var name: String
    var village: String
}
struct D: MyProtocol{
    var name: String
    var village: String
}
struct E: MyProtocol{
    var name: String
    var village: String
}
```

Then on the view controller:

```
var dataArray: [MyProtocol] = []
```

Comment: There's an underlying issue, which this fixes but doesn't remove: why are there 5 structurally identical structs in the first place?